# Create a netbeans project from an external application

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have written a Java application which generates simple java source files.
Now I want to add a functionality to save those files as a Netbeans 7 project.
I have seen in Netbeans projects, there are some Netbeans related files in a folder called `nbproject`. 
So what are those compulsory files, which should be in a Netbeans project?

Is there any Netbeans library, which we too can use to generate those files?

Simply I want to do this:

1. I have some java source files.
2. I want to add Netbeans related file(s)
3. So now this should be a Netbeans project

Comment: create your own simple Netbeans project and have a look at the generated files/folders?

Comment: Thanks David,But I put it as the last solution in my list :) Still looking for an easy way...

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** You write your own NetBeans Module for your tasks

**Method 2:** You create the files with your own program

**Method 3:** You create a project and reuse its files (most of them are based on [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) templates)

**Method 4:** You create your own templates (eg. with Freemarker) and fill them with your programms

*if you don't like #1, you may try a combination of #3 and #4: open generated files and replace all values like projectname, paths etc. which aren't variables yet with your own variables --> use them as Template*

Comment: I like #3: Simple and effective. Any other method is likely to be more complex than just modifying a few template files. Plus, this recipe works just as well for Eclipse projects, IDEA, and any other IDE...